# File deletion using rm command

Tags: python, file, delete-file

I want to make sure that I delete required files.
I have code something like

```
dir="/some/path/"
file = "somefile.txt"
cmd_rm= "rm -rf "+dir + file
os.system(cmd_rm)
```

The `dir` and `file` values are fetched from a database. How can I make sure I never end up running `rm -rf /`?

What things should I check before doing `rm -rf`?

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you are asking. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use the `-r` switch if you just want to remove a single file. Also, there could be spaces in the file name.

Better use the functions in Python's [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module instead:

```
dirname = "/some/path/"
filename = "somefile.txt"
pathname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
if pathname.startswith(dirname):
   os.remove(pathname)
```

Normalizing the path with [`abspath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and comparing it against the target directory avoids file names like "../../../etc/passwd" or similar.

Answer (score 18):

You might consider using [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories) instead since it's a great deal less dangerous than what you're attempting.

Answer (score 6):

First, I suggest you to use the `os.remove()` and `os.rmdir()` functions for working with things like that. You will end up with more portable code and less headache for checking command return.

To check what you are effectively attempting to remove (you may not want to just check "/"), you can use some regular expressions on the generated path or just add a base path to all path returned from you database (depending what you are doing ...).

Comment: If you want to check against the path with a regular expression, don't forget to do something like os.path.realpath and/or os.path.normpath to get a canonical and easy-to-deal-with path string (in particular, without os.path.realpath() (or equivalent code that simply can't be done with regexes), you have no way of knowing that "foo/bar" actually refers to "/")

Answer (score 3):

Use `shutil.rmtree` as Dave Kirby says. If you want to delete the just the file use:

```
dir = "/some/path/" 
file = "somefile.txt" 
cmd = os.path.join(dir, file) 
shutil.rmtree(cmd)
```

If you want to delete the directory use:

```
dir = "/some/path/" 
file = "somefile.txt"  
shutil.rmtree(dir)
```

If the files are write protected make sure you have write permissions before you run this.

Comment: Hmmm, I got an error trying rmtree with a file (though it works fine with a dir). `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory`

Comment: @Pat - how are you executing your script, `python script.py` or `python ./script.py` ?

Comment: Typically something like `python script.py` or even `./script.py`, but in this case I was actually doing it in the ipython REPL.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called `shutil` that provides shell-like file manipulation.  If you want to delete a directory and all files and directories in it then use `shutil.rmtree`.

However it is implemented in python so if you are deleting a huge number of files then spawning rm may be faster, but will fail if the path has a space in it.

Comment: I want to vote you up for the shutil suggestion ( http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html , for a link), but at the same time spawning rm doesn't need to fail because of spaces etc. (use the subprocess module, man!), and speed is almost certainly not an issue (frankly, Python isn't that slow, and I'm fairly sure this op isn't usually CPU-bound).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your mentioning *rm -rf* is not just at random, but is exactly the command you need, why not just to call it? There is a lib allowing a greater integration with shell called [**sh**](https://github.com/amoffat/sh).

```
from sh import rm

path_to_delete = '/some/path'
if os.path.exists(path_to_delete):
    rm('-rf', path_to_delete)
```

PS Make sure you are not root and/or ask for user input to be extra cautious.
And, yes, smoke the man to avoid deleting a single file recursively ;)